# Tighten and loosen a clothing

Tags: word-usage

Of clothes altered to make them fit better,are "loosen" and "tighten" used for that?

Like:

> I tightened my shirt.
>
> I loosened my shirt

P.S. Edited my typos.

Answer (score 1):

For a belt, where simply sliding it to a different notch accomplishes the change, `tightening` or `loosening` are commonly used.

If you mean that a garment is actually altered, though, such as material taken in or buttons moved, it would be more likely someone would say,

> I altered my shirt to make it tighter.

Or

> I altered my shorts to fit more tightly.

BTW, `shorts`, like `pants` and `pajamas`, are always written as plural (likely [because each leg was made and donned separately](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pai1.htm)).

Comment: It was a typo for "shirt".

Comment: Ah! A simple explanation, in short.